# SWIFT: Navigate to UIViewControllers from single function with a variable

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I'm trying to make a function for my navigation without having to type the exact same lines over and over again.

Trying to do so results into an error: "Use of undeclared type 'viewController'"

Am I doing this completely wrong, should I just place these 4 lines on every button just with different identifier and viewController?

```
func navigateTo(identifier:String, viewController:UIViewController) {
   let newVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! viewController
   newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   newVC.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
   self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func btnOneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   navigateTo("myVC", MyViewController)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an instance of `UIViewController` and trying to cast the UIViewController to it in the next line. Modify your function to take in `ViewController.Type` as parameter like this:

```
func navigateTo<ViewController: UIViewController>(identifier: String, viewController: ViewController.Type) {
    let newVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! ViewController
    newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    newVC.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
    self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func btnOneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    navigateTo(identifier: "myVC", viewController: MyViewController.self)
}
```

Comment: Cool, thank you. Both answers are giving me more inside. Being a videographer learning to code all help is welcome. Thank you all for your time and effort to help me.

Comment: Oh cool, Just like any other job you get good at this as you practice and keep asking questions do more research. All the best.

Comment: Oops just noticed my typo, meant insight not inside ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you provide correct identifier...below code works perfectly.

Your Error -> Trying to do so results into an error: "Use of undeclared type 'viewController'"

In this there is a typo mistake for `ViewController` i.e you are trying this - `viewController`

Also always try to do `Optional-Binding` instead to `force-unwarpping` it may cause crash in your app.

```
 func navigateTo(identifier:String, viewController:UIViewController) {
        if let newVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) {
            newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            newVC.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
            self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        navigateTo(identifier: "myVC", viewController: MyViewController())

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I've got it working like so:

```
func navigateToVC(identifier:String, viewController:ViewController.Type) {
   let newVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! ViewController
   newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   newVC.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
   self.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func btnOneTapped(_ sender:Any) {
   navigateToVC(identifier: "myVC", viewController: MyViewController.self)
}
```